# How to escape a nested ADB shell command in bash

Tags: bash, escaping, adb, su

For a bash script that involves issuing a dconf command as user ceres via ADB shell, i need to nest multiple commands.
Manual sequential execution of following three commands works flawless.

```
adb shell
su ceres
dconf write /desktop/asteroid/watchface "'file:///usr/share/asteroid-launcher/watchfaces/$opt.qml'"
```

I learned to escape the dconf keywords to correctly nest dconf in `su ceres -c '<command>'`.

```
su ceres -c 'dconf write /desktop/asteroid/watchface \"'file:///usr/share/asteroid-launcher/watchfaces/$opt.qml'\"'
```

How to nest and escape above command into `adb shell "<command>"`?

```
adb shell "su ceres -c 'dconf write /desktop/asteroid/watchface \"'file:///usr/share/asteroid-launcher/watchfaces/$opt.qml'\"'"
```

Results in dconf reply `error: 0-4:unknown keyword` when issued from the bash script.

Thank you for your help and explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For extremely nested cases I'd stick to `printf %q` instead of doing the quoting manually:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
printf -v cmd %q "'file:///usr/share/asteroid-launcher/watchfaces/$opt.qml'"
printf -v cmd %q "dconf write /desktop/asteroid/watchface $cmd"
adb shell "su ceres -c $cmd"
```

Comment: Great! Got it working.
Thanks for posting the exact commands.
Looking into `man printf` just now to better understand.

Comment: @TimoKönnecke Watch out. Therer are multiple `printf`s. Not all stand-alone versions (which are documented in `man printf`) support `%q` and none of them can support `-v`. What I meant here is the `printf` built into `bash`. You can read its documentation in `help printf`.

Comment: Since the script will likely have some users i will keep that in mind for the case it does not work for some non-bash users. Thank you again!
The ADB transfer is only optional/fallback in the script. Most users will use the ssh/scp method i could get working nested.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `adb shell` reads from standard input. You can use a here document to simplify this (as well as using `sudo` to execute `adb shell` rather than using `su`):

```
sudo -u ceres adb shell <<EOF
dconf write /desktop/asteroid/watchface "file:///usr/share/asteroid-launcher/watchfaces/$opt.qml"
EOF
```

If not, and this might be simpler anyway,

```
sudo -u ceres adb shell -c "dconf write /desktop/asteroid/watchface 'file:///usr/share/asteroid-launcher/watchfaces/$opt.qml'"
```

Comment: I would like to not use sudo on the host the script is executed on. I assume it will be used by regular users that might not have granted root privileges on the machine they are executing it on. The goal is to have a script that loads watchfaces from https://github.com/AsteroidOS/unofficial-watchfaces to a connected AsteroidOS watch to add a little convenience for end-users.
Still thanks! Happy to learn.

Comment: sudo on pc doesn't affect android device. furthermore there is no sudo at all

Comment: You never mentioned this was a PC. (Though I was ignorant of what `adb` was actually doing.)